# Show action bar after hiding it

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I was developing an app for Android 2.3 where the menu sat nicely at the low right together with the back and home buttons.
I've been using

```
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

to fully utilize the screen area.
Now, i'm adapting it to SDK>10, and here the menu sits at the top right in the action bar.
Using the above code line hides the action bar, which means I can't see the menu any more.

I could hide the action bar of course by using

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

Where should I put my

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.show();
```

if I'd like to show the action bar by touching the edges of the screen, just like how the software buttons show up?

Regards
/M